# problems on applyTransaction(), i won`t Rewrite Data object on Row, but updated on RowNode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

i have case that needs to use applyTransaction()

i have AG Grid on Vue, using ApplyTransaction using add: , Update:, Delete:, but when i want to select the data after Update, there is a difference in the object. Data and RowNode.Data . oh data object are not updated but RowNode.Data Updated. Sometimes the object Data are Updated but sometimes not